# Exchange calendar integration with application server external to exchange server

Tags: .net, architecture, interface, exchange-server

I have a requirement to integrate an application with MS Exchange in order to retrieve calendar information.

My company host the application server and would need to contact the client's Exchange server via the public internet (communication would therefore need to be encrypted and authenticated).

The application is a .Net web application.

Does anybody have any resources or ideas on the best way to architect this?

Comment: We've decided to only support 2007+ in order to use Exchange WebServices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on the version of Exchange you are using. Exchange 2007 and 2010 offer WebServices and even a .NET API you can use (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(EXCHG.80).aspx).

If you are working with Exchange 2003, you need to use WebDAV, which is rather complicated. I have a few articles on that topic on my website (http://www.infinitec.de).